# On demand inter-process communication with perl

Tags: perl, architecture, ipc

Imagine inter-processes communication

```
+--------------+                               +------------+
| main_process | ==produces data somewhat to=> | monitoring |
+--------------+                               +------------+
```

where:

- the `main_process` is **running non-stop** and produces some data for `monitoring`
- the `monitoring` is running only sometimes, and when it is running it should read the data produced by `main_process`
- and when the `monitoring` is not running the data produced by `main_process` should be not saved.

The question is: **How to write like "on demand" IPC**?

The code for `main_process` is basically the next (the real one is more complicated):

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
my $box = new BlackBox( callback =>  sub {
    my ($self, $jref) = @_;
    #
    # processing of $jref
    #
});
$box->run();
```

The `callback` is called every 2-5 seconds and as i told above, this process should run *non-stop*. I can't change the BlackBox.

I need:

- write the `processing of $jref` part - what should send `$jref` to *somewhere*
- and the `monitoring` process itself, what should read the data, when it is running...

Don't need any code, need only some pointers to the right direction, or idea how to do this, without filling up my memory or HDD, so the simplest way:

- write the $jref to the file is *not suitable* because it will fill my HDD when the `monitoring` is not running.

If someone care, the `$jref` is a reference to json string, so i can do:

```
 use JSON::XS qw(decode_json):
 my $perlref = decode_json($$jref);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought was "UDP to localhost?"

Variations on that idea include AF_UNIX or a named pipe. With a stream socket you'd do a non-blocking connect, and with the pipe you'd do O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK, and if you get EAGAIN just return without writing.

You can save your file handle and reuse it across multiple calls, just close it and reopen if you get `EPIPE`. You'll want `$SIG{PIPE}='IGNORE';` hopefully the black box doesn't object to that.

The reading side is as simple as `cat $path_to_fifo` or `nc -l -u -p $udpport`, slightly harder if you do an AF_UNIX socket.

Comment: Based on your (and @perreal) suggestion i just found the http://search.cpan.org/~robins/Log-UDP-Client-0.20.0/lib/Log/UDP/Client.pm and http://search.cpan.org/~robins/Log-UDP-Server-0.40.0/lib/Log/UDP/Server.pm what gave me an really simple solution. Thank you. Accepting this because of "UDP" . ;)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like using a socket will be enough. Choose a port number `P` and try to connect to the monitor from the main application (`localhost:P`). If the port is open, send the actual data, not the reference. If the port is closed then just ignore the data. Your monitor will listen on `P` and process any data received through this port.